# Django: Importing models in models.py from outside project does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to define some Django models outside of a Django project folder (I'm just using Django ORM capabilities without web application functionality) and import them into the models.py of an app within Django project.

I know that models.py can be 'split up' by creating a models package, having multiple modules defining models and importing into `__init__.py`, so I thought this would work the same way.

Directory structure is like:

```
- root
  - tasks
    - taskA
      - models.py
    - taskB 
      - models.py
  - orm
    - apps
      - app1
        - models.py
        - base_models.py
        - apps.py
      - app2
        - models.py
        - base_models.py
        - apps.py
    - manage.py
    - settings.py
```

Basically the Django apps categorise the type of model (an abstract base model is defined in appX.base_models.py), and the tasks define and use their own versions /subclasses of the different model types, which are then imported into the django app models.py to be managed by Django

so for example:

in `root.orm.apps.app1.models.py`:

```
from root.tasks.taskA.models import ModelType1A
from root.tasks.taskB.models import ModelType1B
```

However I try launch a task (which calls django.setup()) or manage.py makemigrations, I get:

> RuntimeError: Model class root.tasks.taskA.models.ModelType1A doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

And yes the apps are included in INSTALLED_APPS (it's the import from root.orm.apps.app1.models.py which is causing the error, so Django is detecting the app and trying to get its models but doesn't seem to recognise them when they're imported from outside project or something)

Is there any way to make this work?

Cheers

Comment: Isn't it referring to the presence of the apps.py file. It's usually a class like class TaskAConfig(AppConfig): ... and it contains a name which is a path reference to itself from the root of the project. Can you show us the apps.py files for the root -> tasks -> taskA folders?

Comment: Hi yes I forgot to mention there is an apps.py in each app directory. If this wasn't present then Django wouldn't even get to the stage of trying to import the models for that app would it?

Comment: Inside `ModelType1A` and `ModelType1B` define an `app_label` as `app_label = 'tasks'` under a class `Meta` just like this: `class Meta: app_label = 'tasks'`